# Tomos A3 K Starts but engine has no 'power'

Tags: repair, scooter, moped

So I recently inherited an old Tomos moped [Model A3K with an Encarwi carb] that has been sitting in a garage for a few years and decided to fix it up as a summer project. I've gotten it to start after cleaning the carb, but as soon as I sit on it and try to go somewhere the engine dies. It runs just fine in idle and with the wheel up in the air. I also got it to start with power once when revving the throttle hard; I got to the end of the driveway, stopped, tried to go again and the engine died.

Any idea what the issue might be?

Things I've tried/done:

- Cleaned the carb and jet
- Cleaned the piston chamber, head, exhaust and muffle
- Put clean fuel in the tank and ran it through a few times till it came out clear
- Cleaned out the fuel and air filters
- Replaced and checked the spark and checked the gap

The spark plug looks fine leaning towards too wet when I take it out, it feels like I get compression but I do not have a gauge to measure it and the smoke coming out of the exhaust looks normal. If I ease on the throttle it sometimes makes a clicking noise which I was thinking might be something to do with the transmission but I really don't know whether or not that's normal.